# how do I filter and reject mails in postfix based on the 'to' address

Tags: centos, postfix, spam

My CentOS server is configured for outgoing mail only. I need a filter to reject mails targeted at selected destinations. For example, if I test with

```
> mail -s "test"  spam@trash.com
```

I want this to be rejected and not sent.
I have explored the

> smtpd_recipient_restrictions

flag [and others] but I have not been able to get that working. The logs still show that the mail was sent and removed from the queue.

Within the main.cf file, and under the smtpd_recipient_restrictions, I have:

```
> check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/maps/access_sender
```

where I have, for example

```
@trash.com     REJECT
```

I wish to add that this server relays mails to another but I am hoping that I can filter out unwanted mails before relaying to host. Please help. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Comment: @JennyD: useful comment but downvoting was needless. Thanks anyway

Comment: Please do not make assumptions about who any given vote is from. By philosophy and design votes are anonymous. Some people will downvote without leaving a comment; some people will leave a comment without downvoting; others will do both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `check_sender_access` option only applies to the "From" address. To filter based on the "To" address, you can do this in one of two ways.

---

If you want to filter on just the "To" address, just change the `check_sender_access` to `check_recipient_access` and keep your current hash file.

---

A more extensible way to filter is by headers. Add the following into your `main.cf` file:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Then create the following file at `/etc/postfix/header_checks`:

```
/^To:.*address1@example.com.*$/ DISCARD blocked
/^To:.*address2@example.com.*$/ DISCARD blocked
/^To:.*address3@example.com.*$/ DISCARD blocked
/^To:.*address4@example.com.*$/ DISCARD blocked
```

And restart Postfix.

**Note** - `DISCARD` will still appear to send the message, but the message will be silently discarded. If you want to force the message to be bounced, use `REJECT`.

---

Reference documentation:

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions
http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html